# Performing math on a Python Pandas Group By DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, linear-regression

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the following structure:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
    location_code    month    amount
0    1               1        10
1    1               2        11
2    1               3        12
3    1               4        13
4    1               5        14
5    1               6        15
6    2               1        23
7    2               2        25
8    2               3        27
9    2               4        29
10   2               5        31
11   2               6        33
```

I also have a DataFrame with the following:

```
In [2]: output_df
Out[2]: 
    location_code    regression_coef
0   1                None
1   2                None
```

**What I would like:**

```
output_df = df.groupby('location_code')[amount].apply(linear_regression_and_return_coefficient)
```

I would like to group by the `location code` and then perform a linear regression on the values of `amount` and store the coefficient.  I have tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

gb = df.groupby('location_code')['amount']

x = []
for j in range(6): x.append(j+1)

for location_code, amount in gb:
    trans = amount.tolist()
    x = sm.add_constant(x)
    model = sm.OLS(trans, x)
    results = model.fit()
    output_df['regression_coef'][merchant_location_code] = results.params[1]/np.mean(trans)
```

This code works, but my data set is somewhat large (about 5 gb) and a bit more complex, and this is taking a **REALLY LONG TIME**.  I am wondering if there is a vectorized operation that can do this more efficiently?  I know that using loops on a Pandas DataFrame is bad.

**SOLUTION**

After some tinkering around, I wrote a function that can be used with the `apply` method on a `groupby`.

```
def get_lin_reg_coef(series):
    x=sm.add_constant(range(1,7))
    result = sm.OLS(series, x).fit().params[1]
    return result/series.mean()

gb = df.groupby('location_code')['amount']

output_df['lin_reg_coef'] = gb.apply(get_lin_reg_coef)
```

Benchmarking this versus the iterative solution I had before, with varying input sizes gets:

```
DataFrame Rows    Iterative Solution (sec)    Vectorized Solution (sec)
       370,000    81.42                       84.46
     1,850,000    448.36                      365.66
     3,700,000    1282.83                     715.89
     7,400,000    5034.62                     1407.88
```

Clearly a lot faster as the dataset grows in size!

Comment: `trans_amount` is undefined. Is that supposed to be `amount`?

Comment: Good catch, yes, fixed that.

Comment: `x` is also undefined. Should we just assume that's some constant (how about `1`?

Comment: Right you are, I forgot about the `x`.  This is the way it is in my code.

Comment: You don't need to call `tolist`, just replace `straight` with `trans` -- no need to cast as a list. That will save time replicating the data set (if it's real long, this takes time).

Comment: How many rows and columns in the dataframe? how many location_codes? how many levels of `amount` ?

Comment: 6 columns, 92370574 rows, 2496502 locations, 37 months each, unique amounts for each value.  The dataset is organized by location code and then month, as it appears in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the data, number of records, etc, this code should run faster:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

gb = df.groupby('location_code')['amount']

x = sm.add_constant(range(1,7))

def fit(stuff):
    return sm.OLS(stuff["amount"], x).fit().params[1] / stuff["amount"].mean()

output = gb.apply(fit)
```

Comment: When I call `tolist`, I'm only creating a list of what is in the groupby amount, which is 6 items.

Comment: Does this do the speed up you want?

Comment: No, it does not.  Based on my testing it is approximately the same if not a bit slower.  I am looking for a function that can be applied to the group by object so that I do not have to iterate at all.